# Can't find assertThat

Tags: java, junit, hamcrest

Here is my code

```
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;
import static sun.nio.cs.Surrogate.is;

public class PlayerTest {
  public void should_return_3_when_status_is_3(){
        Player player = new Player();
        assertThat(player.getStatus(),is(3));
    }
}
```

And here is the trace

```
Can't find symbol
符号： method assertThat(int,boolean)
位置： class PlayerTest
```

my iml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module type="JAVA_MODULE" version="4">
  <component name="NewModuleRootManager" inherit-compiler-output="true">
    <exclude-output />
    <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$">
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/test" isTestSource="true" />
    </content>
    <orderEntry type="inheritedJdk" />
    <orderEntry type="sourceFolder" forTests="false" />
    <orderEntry type="module-library" scope="TEST">
      <library>
        <CLASSES>
          <root url="jar://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/lib/junit-4.10.jar!/" />
        </CLASSES>
        <JAVADOC />
        <SOURCES />
      </library>
    </orderEntry>
  </component>
</module>
```

I think I used it before,but it not works now.
Have no clue about what to do.However assertTrue is working.
Ubuntu 11.04 is being used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake is in

```
import static sun.nio.cs.Surrogate.is;
```

`is()` should return a matcher, but whatever this is, it returns boolean. Try `org.hamcrest.Matchers.is` or `org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is` instead.

Comment: I tried `org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is` and `org.hamcrest.Matchers.is` but it's still says can't find.Should I change the setting of the project?

Comment: @ShiheZhang - Update your question with your latest code because this answer should do the trick.

Comment: Can't find symbol
symbol： class is
position： class org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers          Can't find symbol
symbol： method is(int)
position： class PlayerTest

Comment: @DavidHarkness I deleted `import static sun.nio.cs.Surrogate.is;` and add `org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is` instead.

Comment: @ShiheZhang -  I don't see a change to the original question, and the new error message suggests that `is` isn't being imported. Does the new import statement show an error?